# how to add module in opencart

Tags: module, opencart

I have googled for some hours for how to add module in opencart. I do not know which directory should I upload the module. In wordpress it is really clear, but in opeancart I can not understant. 
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple method to add a module is to:

1. copy the upload folder that comes inside the module and simply paste all the folders inside it( e.g. admin,system) to your opencart root it will ask if you want to override files , choose yes(since these will be new files) .
2. go to admin panel > module and click install under the module name

enjoy you will have the module installed !!!

Comment: do you know how to do it on local server like wamp on windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Opencart is very simple MVC structured developed code.

If you have added new extension module then first of follow this link and search ready made extension. download this extension after follow this instructions

just copy and paste fully extension source and paste with match our folder structures and place with them.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension

after you can edit with admin pannel through manager extesions functionality

admin > extension > module

if payment related module then

admin > payment

one more you can also create your new extension with follow opencart code structure.

follow this link

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-opencart-module-development--cms-21873

Answer (score 0):

There is no one directory. Module files go in a number of directories. What you need to do is upload the files of the module keeping the structure within. With most FTP clients you can merge the folders by just uploading the contents of an "upload" folder to your web server's document root directory (`public_html`, `httpdocs` or `htdocs` usually)

Comment: and what is your local server running? xampp, mamp, lamp, wamp?

Comment: it is wamp server on windows 7

Comment: opencart support only php higher version.

Comment: i mean php lower version it can not be support

Comment: @RaviChauhan again that is irrelevant to the question and my answer